# Migration to Azure SQL Database created larger indexes than on-prem

Tags: azure-sql-database, database-migration, database-indexes

Recently migrated an on-prem SQL Server database to Azure SQL database, using Azure Data Studio migration assistant. The process was successful.

However, the size of the final database is much larger than the one on-prem. This is unacceptable given the cost and budget I have.

After checking data files and log, I realized that the indexes for some of the biggest tables are quite large, much larger than the same indexes on-prem.

I'm puzzled on why this is happening.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [Ola Hallengreen scripts](https://ola.hallengren.com/) to rebuild all indexes on the database. After migrations, I recommend rebuilding indexes and update statistics. As stated on [this old Microsoft article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/dilkushp/fragmentation-in-sql-azure), index fragmentation can consume a lot of space on Azure SQL.

After defragmenting indexes, you can consider [page compression](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/5407/azure-sql-database-table-partitioning-example/) to save 40-30% of space more.

In addition, the "online" rebuild of indexes and the isolation level RCSI the Azure SQL add extra bytes to indexes as you can read in [this support article](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/sql-server-blog/why-did-the-size-of-my-indexes-expand-when-i-rebuilt-my-indexes/ba-p/383549). Please rebuild indexes offline to reclaim extra space.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. 
Azure Data Studio assistant already does that. It rebuilds all indexes after copying the data. Do you suggest doing it again?

I'm trying to check for fragmentation on the bigger tables but it's taking forever.

Edit: finally finished, no fragmentation on those large indexes, so still wondering why they are larger than the same indexes on-prem.

Comment: I would try to rebuild the indexes with fill factor equal zero in case Azure Data Studio did the index rebuild with filll factor 80 or 90. If you use Ola's scripts then use @FillFactor = 0 (I think that is the default). ALTER INDEX ALLl on dbo.Table
REBUILD WITH (fillfactor=0). Zero is delafult value for ALTER INDEX also.

Comment: I updated my answer with these facts https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/sql-server-blog/why-did-the-size-of-my-indexes-expand-when-i-rebuilt-my-indexes/ba-p/383549. The ONLINE defrag of indexes and RCSI isolation level of Azure SQL add some extra bytes to indexes. Rebuild them offline option to reclaim some space.

Comment: Sorry it took me forever to reply. I checked RCSI isolation level for the new database (read commited snapshot) and it was not the same as the original database (read commited). I did not know that Azure's default level was that one. After changing that and rebuilding indexes for larger tables, size went down. Thanks!

Comment: Yes, it is something not well known. The default isolation level in Azure SQL is different compared to SQL Server. I glad you reclaimed the storage space at the end.